# Barchart in log scale: cut-off bars, missing values

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a nice barchart from the following data:

```
> counts$counts_16
[1] 46921  1546   248    78    31    15     1     3     2     2     0
> counts$score
[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

With the following code:

```
ggplot(data = counts, aes(x=score, y=counts_16)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=bar.width) + scale_y_continuous(trans=log2_trans())
```

Unfortunately, the result looks a bit odd. First of all, the bars do not start from the x axis, but are located too high.
Then, there is no bar for the 6th value, which should be 1.
For zero, there is a bar, although there should not be one.

Here's an example:

[image: barchart]

Now, I understand why it behaves odd for values of 0 on log scale, but how can I work around it? And how do I fix the other issues?

Answer (score 3):

After a log transformation, the default "baseline" of the bar graph will be 1, rather than zero, because log(0) is -Inf. So when you have a count of 1, there's no bar to display since both the bottom at top of the bar are equal to 1. On the other hand, because log(0) = -Inf, the bar with a count of zero will extend downward beyond the bottom of the y-range of the graph for any lower y-limit less than 1.

**UPDATE:** Regarding your comment, another option is to add points to the plot, so that the you get a point where the y-value equals 1. `ggplot` also includes the top-half of the point for y=0, which sort of marks the zero count. For example:

```
counts = data.frame(score=0:6, counts_16=c(11000,10000,0:4))

ggplot(data = counts, aes(x=score, y=counts_16)) +  
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.1, fill="grey50") +
  geom_point(pch=21, fill="red", size=4) + 
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(1e-1,2e4), breaks=10^seq(-1,4,1), 
                labels=c(0.1, sprintf("%1.0f", 10^seq(0,4,1)))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:6)
```

You can, of course, just go with points (and perhaps a connecting line to guide the eye) and eliminate the bars, which avoids the awkward baseline issue with a bar plot on a log scale.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! As there was no work around given so far, I assume that there is no other way to fix this than to add 1 to all values and adjust the labels of the y axis., or am I missing something?